# Oracle physical standby database received redo has not been applied

Tags: database, oracle

I followed the steps in oracle documentation on creation of a physical standby database.

The link to the configuration steps,
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/create_ps.htm#i63561

When I perform "Step 4 Verfiy that received redo has been applied." my query result is not as expected, following is the result,

SQL> SELECT SEQUENCE#,APPLIED FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG ORDER BY SEQUENCE#;

SEQUENCE# APP

---

```
    5 NO
    6 NO
    7 NO
    8 NO
```

4 rows selected.

Appreciate any advice on how to proceed, thanks.

Comment: need a bit more detail - anything in the alert.log? are the files present on the standby box? (i.e. have they been successfully copied off the primary)? are there any architecture differences between the two boxes? (64 vs 32 bit)?

Comment: Where to look for the alert log? 

Yes the files should be present on the standby box as I verified with the command prior to Step 4, ie. "Step 3   Verify the new redo data was archived on the standby database." and the result was as expected.

Both boxes are the exact same architecture.

Comment: if you haven't specified a location, it will be in $ORACLE_HOME/RDBMS/trace, alternatively run - select value from v$parameter where name = 'background_dump_dest'; and this will give you the location.

Answer (score 1):

try:

alter database recover managed standby database nodelay disconnect from session;